# Variable will not populate with plist data, Swift

Tags: ios, swift, plist

I have been working hard to read plist files to my iOS app, but every method I have used so far has failed.  I am currently using the method described at http://basememara.com/reading-values-plist-bundle-swift/, but in every method I have tried seems to have the same problem.

If this is the code that read the plist file:

```
/**
 Gets the contents of the specified plist file.

 - parameter plistName: property list where defaults are declared
 - parameter bundle: bundle where defaults reside

 - returns: dictionary of values
 */
public static func contentsOfFile(plistName: String, bundle: Bundle? = nil) -> [String : AnyObject] {
    let fileParts = plistName.components(separatedBy: ".")

    guard fileParts.count == 2,
        let resourcePath = (bundle ?? Bundle.main).path(forResource: fileParts[0], ofType: fileParts[1]),
        let contents = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: resourcePath) as? [String : AnyObject]
        let contentsarray = NSArray(contentsOfFile: resourcePath)
        else { return [:] }

    return contents
}
```

and the call is

```
let values = Bundle.contentsOfFile(plistName: "Event.plist")
print(values["Item0"]) // My string value 1.
```

With the plist looking like
[image]

the variable Contents and ContentsArray (for testing) is empty of anything.  I have verified the resourcePath is correct, and there are no errors given, so I don't know what is wrong.  Every other method has the correct path, but never fills the content variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Test", ofType: "plist") {
        let myDict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path)
        print(myDict)
}
```

Another way -

```
if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource:"Test", withExtension: "plist"),
        let myDict = NSDictionary(contentsOf: url) as? [String:Any] {
        print(myDict)
}
```

Also it might have something to do target with target membership as well. Select plist file in your project navigator and check Target Membership section of File inpector.

Comment: File is checked for Target Membership and exsists in finder where it says it will look, but both methods print nil.

Comment: What's the location of file? Is it in main bundle or you are downloading it from somewhere while saving to some other directory like caches?

Comment: It is in the main bundle (.../6922A277-91D7-4F70-A03F-0DD6541C89EF/LG%20Sim%20Builder.app/Event.plist")